# pyppeteer setCookie issue

Tags: python, pyppeteer

When I use pyppeteer with cookies, the below exception is raised

> File "test.py", line 33, in 
>       asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
>
> File "/usr/local/python3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 468,
>   in run_until_complete
>       return future.result()
>
> File "test.py", line 25, in main
>       await page.setCookie(cookies)
>
> File "/usr/local/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/page.py",
>   line 392, in setCookie
>       await self.deleteCookie(*items)
>
> File "/usr/local/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/page.py",
>   line 373, in deleteCookie
>       await self._client.send('Network.deleteCookies', item)
>
> File "/usr/local/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/connection.py",
>   line 200, in send
>       return await callback
>
> pyppeteer.errors.NetworkError: Protocol Error: Invalid parameters name: string value expected

My code listed:

```
async def main():
    cookies = {'name': "", 'name2': ""}  # just a example
    browser = await launch({"executablePath": "/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable"}, args=['--no-sandbox'], headless=True)
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.setCookie(cookies)
    print('after set cookie')
    response = await page.goto('http://example.com/', timeout=100000)

    print('before screenshot')
    await page.screenshot({'path': '/tmp/tmp.png', 'quality': 100, 'fullPage': True})
    await browser.close()

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Answer (score 2):

According to project github: https://github.com/miyakogi/pyppeteer/issues/94

Adding {'url': "your url", 'name': "", 'value': ""} Can fix the problem.